# django: why does accessing a page from web browser freeze the server?

Tags: python, django, browser

I've made a django app, running it w/ the built-in server for now (just for testing). I have programs which access urls multiple times per second on the app without any issues. However, when I view an admin page, or one of those URLs that the program visits, in a web browser, the server freezes for many seconds. Why might this be the case, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

The Django development server only does 1 request at a time. I believe that's why you have the issue.

Comment: hmm but several different programs are hitting it and their requests work fine, even though it's only 1 at a time. why does the browser request freeze it up?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome, this could be a known issue that is fixed today in trunk by jezdez:

https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/16427